# Passing inputText value from inside a repeat

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I've an object in salesforce and i want to make a form to enter values based on how many related list objects there are. Since i dont know how many related list objects there are i wanted to try and use a repeat on the page.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!prompts}" var="pmpt">
  <div>
    <label>{!pmpt.Name}</label>
    <div>
      <apex:inputText value="{!pmpt.DefaultValue__c}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

So the code above gets the list of related list records (prompts) from the controller and displays a label and the inputText value assigned to it with the default value displayed. This works fine but i don't know how to read these values back in my controller when the user changes them from the default. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to assign to a variable in your Controller.. instead of

```
<apex:inputText value="{!pmpt.DefaultValue__c}"/>
```

it would be

```
<apex:inputText value="{!Your_Controller_Variable}"/>
```

This way when you submit the form the values in your input fields would be assigned to your variables in the controller and then you can perform any process you want with them

**Now, since you have a repeat...** and every input is related to a different record, what you can do is to change the **inputText** to **inputField**, then add a button submit the form on your page.. this will show the current values for each object field and.. will update the records on your list (the one you are using in the repeat). Have it like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pmpt.DefaultValue__c}"/>
```

The inputField would assign the value to the corresponding record field on its own when you submit the form.